# Raspberry Pi bcm_host include directories

Tags: graphics, raspberry-pi, egl

I'm trying to write a simple program that uses EGL, but when I include bcm_host.h, gcc says it doesn't exist, so I add /opt/vc/include to the makefile, it says that another header is missing, I add another directory, and now, after 6 folders, I don't really want to do it anymore but gcc wants more. I have looked at the /opt/vc/src/hello_pi/Makefile.include file, and it adds just 3 folders. So the question is: what am I doing wrong?

Here's the makefile:

```
LIB_DIR = -L/opt/vc/lib
INCLUDE_DIRS = -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/ -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmc_host/linux -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vchi -I/usr/include/SDL -I-

LIBS = -lSDL

bin:
    gcc $(LIB_DIRS) $(INCLUDE_DIRS) $(LIBS)  main.c
```

Comment: Please show us your makefile. It is hard to see what the problem is from your description.

Answer (score 0):

I included bcm_host.h in a project where I was using code from the dispmax example.  I have very similar makefile settings, with the exception that I added -lbcm_host as a library:

```
# Include the Broadcom hardware interface library
XINCDIR += /opt/vc/include
XINCDIR += /opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads
XLIBS += -L/opt/vc/lib/ -lbcm_host
```

That worked for me, although I wasn't trying to use EGL specifically.  You probably need -lEGL instead or in addition.